# Spring integration TCP Server with multi thread example

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

Spring integration has excellent example to TCP Server. But it seems to be using single thread for every socket connection.

Is there any example on how to create TCP Server which can process requests with multiple threads? Better yet, is there any example to use thread pooling in TCP Server.

I would appreciate if you can provide any links.

Thanks

Comment: If you could link to the example you are talking about, that would be helpful.

Comment: TCP Client Server example is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server . To test with multi threads, add a delay in EchoService. You can use  junit tests to send requests or JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `using-nio="true"` when processing a large number of sockets and a thread pool is shared across the connections.

For a small number of sockets it's generally faster to use a single thread per socket.

Comment: Gary, Does spring integration create a thread to process the request if using-nio="true" ?  Does it use thread pool?  Is there a way to set the pool size ?

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-endpoint-reference) (`task-executor`) - by default it uses an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` but you can inject a bounded `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` - but you need to be careful that the pool has enough threads to satisfy the number of connections and/or message rate. This is discussed in [A Note About NIO](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#note_nio).

Comment: I am bit confused on the rejection policy for task-executor.

Comment: It's pretty simple. If the threads are all in use and the queue has a limit and it's full, the policy determines what happens if a thread attempts to submit a new task. Caller runs means the task runs immediately on the submitting thread, bypassing the queue. Abort means an exception is thrown which, in this case, will cause the socket to be closed.

Comment: I did not understand 'Caller runs means the task runs immediately on the submitting thread'  what is submitting thread? Is it the thread that is listening for socket connections from clients?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward - when a thread (any thread) submits a task to an executor, the request is put in a queue. If there's an idle thread in the pool, the task is picked up and run. If all the threads are in use, the first thread to complete its current task picks up the next task in the queue. If the queue is full when the task is submitted, the result depends on the policy; caller runs means the submitter runs the task immediately. Here, there are two task types (read and assemble) and 2 submitter types. The IO event handler submits read tasks; the read task submits assemble tasks.